# Rails Blogger.com integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogger

I'm looking to retrieve the latest two posts from a Blogger.com account that belongs to me.

What is the best way of doing so using Ruby on Rails 2.3.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute easiest way is to use your blog's RSS feed.

Here are some good, simple, article on how to parse RSS feeds in Rails:

http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2005/05/11/parsing-a-rss-feed

http://rubyrss.com/

Comment: thanks! that's what I ended up going with. There's a really awesome railscast by Ryan Bates about parsing feeds with Feedzirra:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Use Ruby and the API of blogger.com.

Comment: could you elaborate on that please?